# Hadoop node high availablility

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

How to have high-availability of namenode?
Are we supposed to configure something in cluster.(Are we supposed to have 2 nodes(namenodes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many resources on the internet on how to do that in hadoop v1 e.g.  http://www.hadoopsphere.com/2012/11/understanding-high-availability-options.html or http://hortonworks.com/blog/ha-namenode-for-hdfs-with-hadoop-1-0-part-1/

In Hadoop 2.0 this is inherently solved.

Comment: Another [blog](http://www.cloudera.com/blog/2012/03/high-availability-for-the-hadoop-distributed-file-system-hdfs/) on the same.

Answer (score 0):

Datanode: They do the actual work..

NameNode: Does the job of managing the DataNodes.

A cluster can have many DataNodes but only one NameNode.
In a cluster of physical boxes typically one box runs the NameNode while other boxes run the DataNodes.

It is a good idea to keep NameNode separate from the DataNodes which do the grunt work. The reason being that the NameNode work is already memory wise intensive. That the NameNode can be a single point of failure for your cluster does not help too.
Hence the oft repeated advice to keep NameNode running on a separate highly available server with bulletproof reliability.